# Tag Input compatible con Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, nodejs

Es algo muy básico por lo que me sorprende no haber encontrado la solución en una investigación por npmjs y en internet en general. Necesito un "input tag" para que justamente los ítems ingresados en ese campo los pueda extraer en un Array para posteriormente enviarlos con mi request y almacenar esos datos. Acá un ejemplo de lo que estoy buscando:

[image: Algo como esto]

Esta captura es de Materialize.css que si tiene esta característica integrada. ***Recalco, necesito esto pero compatible con Boostrap4. Obviamente se puede hacer con JS vanilla pero la solución que estoy buscando es algo prefabricado ya pues los tags son un elemento común en la web y sé que ya existe solo necesito encontrar el recurso.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar jQuery TagEditor.

Su documentación la hallas en: https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html

```js
const isEmail = input => /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/.test(input);

$('#email-tags').tagEditor({
  placeholder: 'Agrega tus correos y da enter...',
  beforeTagSave: (field, editor, tags, tag, val) => {

    // make sure it is a formally valid email
    if (!isEmail(val)) {
      console.log(`"${val}" is not a valid email`);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.css");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/caret/1.3.4/jquery.caret.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<form action="Registro" method="post">
  <!-- registro -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Apellidos</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>área</label><br/>
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
      <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
      <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Coreo electronico</label>
    <input id="email-tags" />
  </div>



  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarme</button>
</form>
<!-- Cierrra form registro -->
```

Como verás básicamente llamas a una función llamada `tagEditor` y de parámetro le pasas un objeto con la configuración que quieres.

Bootstrap4

```js
const isEmail = input => /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/.test(input);

$('#email-tags').tagEditor({
  placeholder: 'Agrega tus correos y da enter...',
  beforeTagSave: (field, editor, tags, tag, val) => {

    // make sure it is a formally valid email
    if (!isEmail(val)) {
      console.log(`"${val}" is not a valid email`);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.css");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/caret/1.3.4/jquery.caret.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<form action="Registro" method="post">
  <!-- registro -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Apellidos</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>área</label><br/>
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
      <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
      <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
      <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Coreo electronico</label>
    <input id="email-tags" />
  </div>



  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarme</button>
</form>
<!-- Cierrra form registro -->
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351967/6999690

Comment: Me aparecen errores:Uncaught Error:Method NaN does not exist on jQuery.caret
    at Function.error (jquery.js?1157:334)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.caret (jquery.caret.js?4e22:423)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (jquery.tag-editor.js?ab56:175)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery.js?1157:5429)
    at HTMLUListElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js?1157:5233)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js?1157:8715)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (jquery.js?1157:8793)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?1157:381)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js?1157:203)
    at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js?1157:8792)

Comment: No podría decírtelo sin ver tu código, te recomiendo hacer una pregunta nueva para ese caso que es más específico.

Comment: Olvidalo amigo, no había leído que depende de jQuery Caret, por lo tanto hay que impementar ese plugin además de tagEditor para que funcione correctamente. ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: El ejemplo está con boostrap 3. ¿Es compatible con boostrap 4?

Comment: @FernandoPalma sí, agregué el ejemplo también con con bootstrap 4 :)